# How to validate unique constraint on django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can i validate an unique constraint with a key that is not on the request payload?

The key that i need to validate are `user_id` and `sku` but the request does not contain the `user_id` key.

Example of payload:

```
{'sku': '123', data: []}
```

The serializers:

```
class ProductConfiguration(serializers.Serializer):

    min_quantity = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    price = serializers.DecimalField(
        required=True,
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=10,
        coerce_to_string=False
    )


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sku = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    data = ProductConfiguration(many=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WholeSale

        # the "id" and "user_id" columns should not be included on the response
        exclude = ['id', 'user']
```

I need to validate that the `user` and `sku` key already exist.

By default if the two keys `user_id` and `sku` were on the payload `drf` could take care of `Unique` error, how can i validate this two keys if one of them are not on the payload?

Answer (score 2):

you can get user data from request

> request.user

Maybe pass it in to serializer from view

```
data = request.data
data['user_id'] = request.user.pk
serializer = ProductSerializer(data)
```

in serializer you could do

```
def validate(self, data):
    user = data.get('user_id')
    sku = data.get('sku')

    record = WholeSale.objects.filter(user=user, sku=sku).first()

    if not record:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("This combo doesn't exist")

    return super().validate(data)
```

Comment: I would use: `if not WholeSale.objects.filter(user=user, sku=sku).exists(): raise Validation error`

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if not Sku.objects.get(sku=attrs['sku']).exists() or not User.objects.get(id=attrs['id']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Something doesn't exist")
        
        return attrs

    sku = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    data = ProductConfiguration(many=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WholeSale
        exclude = ['id', 'user']
```

Comment: the question says that the `user` and `sku` must be validated together...

Comment: This is a rough idea you can use to push forward in the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have this model structure ( i am only taking the `sku` and `user` field). To achieve what you trying to do, in class meta provide a unique together constraints,

```
class WholeSale(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sku = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'sku']
```

*OR*,

simply overwrite the `validate_unique` method to achieve validation on both `user` and `sku` fields together.

```
class WholeSale(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sku = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)

    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # super(WholeSale, self).validate_unique(*args, **kwargs) # python2
        super().validate_unique(*args, **kwargs) # python3
        if self.__class__.objects.filter(user=self.user, sku=self.sku).\
            exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                message='This (user, sku) already exists.',
            )
```

**No need to validate explicitly from serializer**

Comment: at least with latest django rest framework = 3.11.1 this function is not called at all :(